# get_xticklabels() contains empty text instances

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate the x tick labels in a plot. I created a general function that plots in the style I want to plot. I do the following:

```
labels=ax2.get_xticklabels()
for i,label in labels:
   labels[i]=label.get_text()
ax2.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=30)
```

This produced plots with no x_tick labels, so I dug deeper:
I had it print the label as it was looping through and they were empty text instances. However, this is where it gets weird: When I just get the labels (labels=ax2.get_xticklabels()), and have the plot function return the list of text instances (return labels), the Text instances in the list do have the correct string, and the code above produces a list of strings as intended. I am not sure why the text instances are empty when I try to edit it inside of the function, but correct when I have the function return labels unedited. Any advice?

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example with the code from where you are calling the function, and the error you get?

Answer (score 31):

I will answer according to the title in your question because I don't understand the explanation that follows it.

The tick labels are not populated until the figure is drawn.

```
plt.plot([1, 2])
ax = plt.gca()
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    print(label)
```

Output:

```
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
```

When you call `plt.draw()` the tick labels are populated:

```
plt.plot([1, 2])
ax = plt.gca()
plt.draw()
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    print(label)
```

Output:

```
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'0.0')
Text(0.2,0,'0.2')
Text(0.4,0,'0.4')
Text(0.6,0,'0.6')
Text(0.8,0,'0.8')
Text(1,0,'1.0')
Text(0,0,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the kind of solution you wanted. I had a `DataFrame` whose x-ticks are all names of different cases. I had to do something like this.

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(my_df.index)))
ax.set_xticklabels([case for case in my_df.columns], rotation=30)
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem,

```
for tl in ax2.get_xticklabels():
    tl.set_rotation(30)
```

works well, so I don't understand the downvotes. Since it is the same function (get_xticklabels()) and rotating through does work, drawing the labels first does not seem to be the problem at all, yet it is the most upvoted answer....

Comment: This is just a copy of another older answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36065415/14536215

Answer (score -2):

```
for tl in ax2.get_xticklabels():
    tl.set_rotation(30)
```