# Getting empty tick labels before showing a plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, label

I'm experiencing a similar issue to the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700935/get-xticklabels-contains-empty-text-instances). I don't understand why the tick label text is an empty string:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    print(label)

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
Text(0,0,'')
```

I get the same result with `ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()` but the plotted graph shows eight labelled ticks on the x-axis when saved or shown. However, if I ask for the labels *after* I show the plot, then the `labels` list is properly populated. Of course, it's a bit late to do anything about changing them then.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    print(label)
```

Output:

```
Text(0,0,'0')
Text(1,0,'1')
Text(2,0,'2')
Text(3,0,'3')
Text(4,0,'4')
Text(5,0,'5')
Text(6,0,'6')
Text(7,0,'7')
```

Why does this happen (Mac OS X Yosemite, Matplotlib 1.5.1) and how can I get my labels *before* I show or save my plot?

Comment: what is the purpose of getting `xticklabels`? You can always have your own custom `xticklabels` by using `ax.set_xticklabels(["0","1"])` (just an example). provide a list of strings as labels. If there are less no.of strings provided in the list, remaining `ticklabels` will show empty. reference: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You've correctly identified the problem: before you call `plt.show()` nothing is explicitly set. This is because matplotlib avoids static positioning of the ticks unless it has to, because you're likely to want to interact with it: if you can `ax.set_xlim()` for example.

In your case, you can draw the figure canvas with `fig.canvas.draw()` to trigger tick positioning, so you can retrieve their value.

Alternatively, you can explicity set the xticks that will in turn set the the axis to `FixedFormatter` and `FixedLocator` and achieve the same result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim(0,6)

# Must draw the canvas to position the ticks
fig.canvas.draw()
# Or Alternatively
#ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks())

labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    print(label.get_text())

plt.show()

Out:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: This solution does not work when the `pdf`-backend is used. In this case,  `ax.get_xticklabels()` is unaffected by `fig.canvas.draw()`.
While the alternate solution `ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks())` has ticklabels produced, indeed, they differ from the ones that would otherwise be produced:

`ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks())` produces 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 ...
 
`fig.canvas.draw()` produces 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: So I'm not using subplots() and I also have empty `ax.get_yticklabels()` when looping. And a `fig.canvas.draw()` give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

As Julien Marrec, you have to call `fig.canvas.draw()`.
Good thing is it doesn't wait for input after opening window and directly displays the chart(or returns control to next line in code)

So I made a workaround here:

```
# First call the .draw() function and take whatever values your need.
fig.canvas.draw()
x_lab = axes.get_xticklabels()
y_lab = axes.get_yticklabels()
z_lab = axes.get_zticklabels()

# Now we close the figure since we are done getting values
# This will be a fast process and look like figure never opened
plt.close()
```