# How to set the matplotlib axes tick labels fontweight to bold?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying the following code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
#data is a geopandas DataFrame 
data.plot(ax=ax1, kind='bar', color= barcolor, width= 0.8)
ax1.set_yticklabels(ax1.get_yticklabels(), weight='bold')
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, weight='bold', size=12)
```

Only x-axis gets affected by this code and y-axis labels are getting removed.

Comment: Provide a complete code. Your current information is incomplete and useless

Comment: Added complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `get_yticklabels()` to `get_yticks` works for me:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar([0,1],[2,3])
ax1.set_yticklabels(ax1.get_yticks(), weight='bold')
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticks(), rotation=0, weight='bold', size=12)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122923/getting-empty-tick-labels-before-showing-a-plot-in-matplotlib) is the answer for reasons behind this kind of error. It's because matplotlib avoids static positioning. Adding the following code just after `data.plot()` helped too:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```