# Error Getting Numeric Value of Plot Tick Label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting a `ValueError: could not convert string to float` when converting tick label values into numeric types.

According to the [Text documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) though, a string should be returned.

**MVP**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( range( 5 ), range( 5 ) )

for lbl in ax.get_xticklabels():
    float( lbl.get_text() )
```

Comment: if you do `print(lbl.get_text())` what is the output?

Comment: It seems to be the string, e.g. -0.5

Comment: Is it possible something strange is going on with the Formatter?

Comment: when I use you code and change `float( lbl.get_text() )` to`print(float(lbl.get_text())` I get empty strings which can not be converted to string

Comment: If I before the for loop you put `plt.show()` then curiosly enough I get the expected output your problem is explained in one of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700935/get-xticklabels-contains-empty-text-instances bascally until you dont call `plt.show()` the xticks are not populated

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the help, that was the issue. In my actual case I think there was a hangover during the print statements because I was looping over some subplots.

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez If you want to post an answer I'd definitely accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code gets the xtixk labels before being populated
so if you do

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( range( 5 ), range( 5 ) )

for lbl in ax.get_xticklabels():
    print(lbl.get_text())
```

You will see that all the labels are empty strings. If you put `plt.show()` before the for loop it should populate the list and you should be able to get the labels.