# Set (conditional) font weight for tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have an example plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, 100)
y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15, left=0.2)
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

[image]

What I want to do is make the tick labels, in best case conditionally, bold. For example, to print the tick labels 0.0 and 0.6 on the y-axis bold, the other ones medium. 
I know I can change the font weight of the axis labels using the `fontweight` argument, like:

```
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontweight='bold')
```

But I can't find anything similar for the tick labels. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude way of doing this is as follows

```
ax.get_xticklabels()[1].set_fontweight("bold")
ax.get_xticklabels()[5].set_fontweight("bold")
```

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontfamily) is the official documentation of all the text manipulations.

Comment: I know this is not 'conditional' but I am unable to get info regarding manipulation of `tick_label`. I had asked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943725/matplotlib-setting-text-to-ticker) before but did not get any response. There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700935/get-xticklabels-contains-empty-text-instances) questions suggest using 'plt.draw()' first but I am still not able to achieve that.