# sns: Labels disappear/clear after calling set_xticklabels

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I print a seaborn line plot using the below code.

```
timeplot = sns.lineplot(x='YearMonth', y='count', data=delivered_by_month)
```

This works fine, but x axis labels are overlapping, so I wanted to rotate them.

So I added an additional line like this after the above line.

```
timeplot.set_xticklabels(labels=timeplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, ha="right")
```

Now X-axis labels just disappeared.
I confirmed that all labels got cleared by running the below code.

```
for m in timeplot.get_xticklabels():
  print (m)
```

For this, I got an output like below.

```
Text(0, 0, '')
Text(1, 0, '')
Text(2, 0, '')
Text(3, 0, '')
Text(4, 0, '')
```

If I print labels before the rotation code, I get a proper output like below.

```
Text(0, 0, '2010-10')
Text(1, 0, '2010-11')
Text(2, 0, '2010-12')
Text(3, 0, '2010-2')
Text(4, 0, '2010-3')
```

Any input will be helpful.

Comment: You want to [rotate the labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353146/4124317).

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same issue and this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41131528/14396570

Apparently, `timeplot.get_xticklabels()` is empty until the graph is drawn, so you have to call `plt.draw()` before setting x tick labels, like so:

```
timeplot = sns.lineplot(x='YearMonth', y='count', data=delivered_by_month)
plt.draw()
timeplot.set_xticklabels(labels=timeplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, ha="right")
```